# How to access method from other class method that is used as a callback?

Tags: javascript

I have the following Javascript class:

```
class App {

    log_text(text) {
        console.log(text)
    }

    process_response(response) {
        this.log_text(response) // Uncaught TypeError: this.log_text is not a function
        // self.log_text(response) // Uncaught TypeError: self.log_text is not a function
    }

    do_stuff() {
        this.log_text('hello') // OK
    }

    fetch_data() {
        jQuery.get('http://example.com/data/sample.txt', this.process_response, 'text')
    }
}
```

When calling the method `do_stuff`, I can access `log_text` fine by calling `this.log_text`. However, the method `process_response`, which is used as a callback handler for `jQuery.get` as in this example, fails because `this` represents a totally different object in that context.

Similarly, `self.log_text` also throws a TypeError.

What would be a possible (or the correct) way to call `log_text` from `process_response` as in this example?

Comment: Have you tried `this.process_response.bind(this)` in jQuery.get?

Comment: either you can bind the process_response function with this in the class constructor or alternatively you can use es6 arrow syntax as well it does the binding job for you.

Comment: Thanks @Satpal and warl0ck. That is very helpful. Satpal, would you maybe add that as an alternative answer to Bill Hayden's?

Answer (score 3):

What's happening is that you are passing your process_response function and that is all, as you've seen the context of this changes. One fix is to wrap it using arrow syntax, which will preserve the value of this when jQuery fires the callback.

```js
 fetch_data() {
        jQuery.get('http://example.com/data/sample.txt', (r)=> this.process_response(r), 'text')
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Function.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) to set the context of `process_response` function

```js
fetch_data() {
  jQuery.get('http://example.com/data/sample.txt', this.process_response.bind(this), 'text')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an arrow function, which has a lexical `this` -

```
fetch_data() {
  jQuery.get
    ( 'http://example.com/data/sample.txt'
    , r => this.process_response(r)
    , 'text'
    )
}
```

Or use `Function#bind` which binds a context (and optionally some arguments) to a function -

```
fetch_data() {
  jQuery.get
    ( 'http://example.com/data/sample.txt'
    , this.process_response.bind(this)
    , 'text'
    )
}
```

Or as was done historically, preserve context with a var; this is now less preferred to the above techniques -

```
fetch_data() {
  var ctx = this
  jQuery.get
    ( 'http://example.com/data/sample.txt'
    , function (r) { ctx.process_response(r) }
    , 'text'
    )
}
```

---

New JS features will improve your quality of life, however. Consider coercing your *jqXHR* to a *Promise* so you can use `async` and `await` -

```
const get = (opts = {}) =>
  new Promise
    ( (resolve, reject) =>
        $.get(opts)
         .done((req, status, res) => resolve(res))
         .fail((req, status, err) => reject(err))
    )
```

The result is flatter code and many extraneous functions like `fetch_data` and `process_response` are no longer necessary. Even better, our minds are freed from thinking about binding functions and dynamic contexts -

```
class App {

    log_text(text) {
        console.log(text)
    }

    async main () {
      const res = await
        get ({ url: '/data/sample.txt', dataType: 'text' })

      this.log_text(res)
    }

}
```

---

You could even set default options for your `get` wrapper -

```
const defaultOpts =
  { dataType: 'text' }

const get = (opts = {}) =>
  new Promise
    ( (resolve, reject) =>
        $.get({ ...defaultOpts, ...opts })
         .done((req, status, res) => resolve(res))
         .fail((req, status, err) => reject(err))
    )
```

Then using it -

```
async main () {
  const res = await
    get ({ url: '/data/sample.txt' })

  this.log_text(res)
  // ...
}
```